# Proxy server error

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

I'm using a local proxy server to tunnel my RMI traffic over HTTP to my webserver.

My Proxyserver is from jProxy(http://jproxy.sourceforge.net/).

I modified it to run inside my RMI application, listening and forwarding traffic to port 80 on my webserver and back again.

For handling this tunnel i am using TunnelSocket.

Posting code below:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 * Socket that tunnels through a proxy by using the CONNECT command.
 * <P>
 * To connect to <CODE>bar.foo.com</CODE>, port 1234, through the proxy
 * <CODE>evilproxy.mydomain.com</CODE> this socket implementation will sent an
 * initial plain text line to the proxy of the form
 * <P>
 * <CENTER><CODE>CONNECT bar.foo.com:1234 HTTP/1.0</CODE></CENTER>
 * <P>
 * and if all goes well the proxy will respond <CENTER>
 * <CODE>HTTP/1.0 200 OK</CODE></CENTER>
 * <P>
 * Hereafter, all that is sent to the proxy will be forwarded to the remote
 * host, and all that the remote host returns will be forwarded to this socket.
 */
public class TunnelSocket extends Socket {

    /**
   *
   */
    public TunnelSocket(String proxyHost, int proxyPort, InetAddress remoteAddress, int remotePort) throws IOException {
        this(proxyHost, proxyPort, remoteAddress.getHostName(), remotePort);
    }

    /**
   *
   */
    public TunnelSocket(String proxyHost, int proxyPort, InetAddress remoteAddress, int remotePort,
            InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        this(proxyHost, proxyPort, remoteAddress.getHostName(), remotePort, localAddress, localPort);
    }

    /**
   *
   */
    public TunnelSocket(String proxyHost, int proxyPort, String remoteHost, int remotePort) throws IOException {
        super(proxyHost, proxyPort);
        tunnel(remoteHost, remotePort);
    }

    /**
   *
   */
    public TunnelSocket(String proxyHost, int proxyPort, String remoteHost, int remotePort, InetAddress localAddress,
            int localPort) throws IOException {
        super(proxyHost, proxyPort, localAddress, localPort);
        tunnel(remoteHost, remotePort);
    }

    /**
   *
   */
    private void tunnel(String remoteHost, int remotePort) throws IOException {
        OutputStream output = getOutputStream();
        InputStream input = getInputStream();

        String msg = "CONNECT " + remoteHost + ":" + remotePort + " HTTP/1.0\n" + "User-Agent: "
                + sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.userAgent + "\r\n\r\n";
        byte b[];
        try {
            b = msg.getBytes("ASCII7");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ignored) {
            b = msg.getBytes();
        }
        output.write(b);
        output.flush();

        byte[] reply = new byte[200];
        int replyLen = 0;
        int newlinesSeen = 0;
        boolean headerDone = false;
        boolean error = false;

        while (newlinesSeen < 2) {
            int i = input.read();
            if (i < 0) {
                throw new IOException("Unexpected EOF from proxy");
            }
            if (i == '\n') {
                headerDone = true;
                newlinesSeen++;
            } else if (i != '\r') {
                newlinesSeen = 0;
                if (!headerDone && replyLen < reply.length) {
                    reply[replyLen++] = (byte) i;
                }
            }
        }

        String replyStr;
        try {
            replyStr = new String(reply, 0, replyLen, "ASCII7");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ignored) {
            replyStr = new String(reply, 0, replyLen);
        }

        if (!replyStr.startsWith("HTTP/1.0 200")) {
            throw new IOException("Unable to tunnel. " + "Proxy returns \"" + replyStr + "\"");
        }
    }

}
```

**This code establishes a connection between the webserver and proxy.**

And here is my jProxy.java code:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class jProxy extends Thread
{
    public static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 8080;

    private ServerSocket server = null;
    private int thisPort = DEFAULT_PORT;
    private String fwdServer = "";
    private int fwdPort = 0;
    private int ptTimeout = ProxyThread.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;
    private int debugLevel = 3;
    private PrintStream debugOut = System.out;
    private Logger log;

    /* the proxy server just listens for connections and creates
     * a new thread for each connection attempt (the ProxyThread
     * class really does all the work)
     */
    public jProxy (int port)
    {
        thisPort = port;
    }

    public jProxy (int port, String proxyServer, int proxyPort)
    {
        thisPort = port;
        fwdServer = proxyServer;
        fwdPort = proxyPort;
    }

    public jProxy (int port, String proxyServer, int proxyPort, int timeout)
    {
        thisPort = port;
        fwdServer = proxyServer;
        fwdPort = proxyPort;
        ptTimeout = timeout;
    }


    /* allow the user to decide whether or not to send debug
     * output to the console or some other PrintStream
     */
    public void setDebug (int level, PrintStream out)
    {
        debugLevel = level;
        debugOut = out;
    }


    /* get the port that we're supposed to be listening on
     */
    public int getPort ()
    {
        return thisPort;
    }


    /* return whether or not the socket is currently open
     */
    public boolean isRunning ()
    {
        if (server == null)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }


    /* closeSocket will close the open ServerSocket; use this
     * to halt a running jProxy thread
     */
    public void closeSocket ()
    {
        try {
            // close the open server socket
            server.close();
            // send it a message to make it stop waiting immediately
            // (not really necessary)
            /*Socket s = new Socket("localhost", thisPort);
            OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
            os.write((byte)0);
            os.close();
            s.close();*/
        }  catch(Exception e)  { 
            if (debugLevel > 0)
                debugOut.println(e);
        }

        server = null;
    }


    public void run()
    {
        try {
            // create a server socket, and loop forever listening for
            // client connections
            server = new ServerSocket(thisPort);
            if (debugLevel > 0)
                debugOut.println("Started jProxy on port " + thisPort);

            while (true)
            {
                Socket client = server.accept();
                ProxyThread t = new ProxyThread(client);
                t.setDebug(debugLevel, debugOut);
                t.setTimeout(ptTimeout);
                t.start();
            }
        }  catch (Exception e)  {
            if (debugLevel > 0)
                debugOut.println("jProxy Thread error: " + e);
        }

        closeSocket();
    }

}
```

And ProxyThread.java code:

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.net.Socket;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

class ProxyThread extends Thread {
    private Socket pSocket;
    private String fwdServer = "";
    private int fwdPort = 0;
    private int debugLevel = 0;
    private PrintStream debugOut = System.out;
    private Logger log;

    // the socketTimeout is used to time out the connection to
    // the remote server after a certain period of inactivity;
    // the value is in milliseconds -- use zero if you don't want
    // a timeout
    public static final int DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = 20 * 1000;
    private int socketTimeout = DEFAULT_TIMEOUT;

    public ProxyThread(Socket s) {
        pSocket = s;
    }

    public ProxyThread(Socket s, String proxy, int port) {
        pSocket = s;
        fwdServer = proxy;
        fwdPort = port;
    }

    public void setTimeout(int timeout) {
        // assume that the user will pass the timeout value
        // in seconds (because that's just more intuitive)
        socketTimeout = timeout * 1000;
    }

    public void setDebug(int level, PrintStream out) {
        debugLevel = level;
        debugOut = out;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            // client streams (make sure you're using streams that use
            // byte arrays, so things like GIF and JPEG files and file
            // downloads will transfer properly)
            BufferedInputStream clientIn = new BufferedInputStream(pSocket.getInputStream());
            BufferedOutputStream clientOut = new BufferedOutputStream(pSocket.getOutputStream());
            // the socket to the remote server
            Socket server = null;

            // other variables
            byte[] request = null;
            byte[] response = null;
            int requestLength = 0;
            int responseLength = 0;
            int pos = -1;
            StringBuffer host = new StringBuffer("xx.xxx.xxx.xxx");
            String hostName = "";
            int hostPort = 80;

            // get the header info (the web browser won't disconnect after
            // it's sent a request, so make sure the waitForDisconnect
            // parameter is false)
            request = getHTTPData(clientIn, host, false);
            requestLength = Array.getLength(request);

            // separate the host name from the host port, if necessary
            // (like if it's "servername:8000")
            hostName = host.toString();
            pos = hostName.indexOf(":");
            if (pos > 0) {
                try {
                    hostPort = Integer.parseInt(hostName.substring(pos + 1));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                hostName = hostName.substring(0, pos);
            }

            // either forward this request to another proxy server or
            // send it straight to the Host
            try {
                if ((fwdServer.length() > 0) && (fwdPort > 0)) {
                    server = new Socket(fwdServer, fwdPort);
                } else {
                    server = new Socket(hostName, hostPort);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // tell the client there was an error
                String errMsg = "HTTP/1.0 500\nContent Type: text/plain\n\n" + "Error connecting to the server:\n" + e + "\n";
                clientOut.write(errMsg.getBytes(), 0, errMsg.length());
            }

            if (server != null) {
                server.setSoTimeout(socketTimeout);
                BufferedInputStream serverIn = new BufferedInputStream(server.getInputStream());
                BufferedOutputStream serverOut = new BufferedOutputStream(server.getOutputStream());

                // send the request out
                serverOut.write(request, 0, requestLength);
                serverOut.flush();

                // and get the response; if we're not at a debug level that
                // requires us to return the data in the response, just stream
                // it back to the client to save ourselves from having to
                // create and destroy an unnecessary byte array. Also, we
                // should set the waitForDisconnect parameter to 'true',
                // because some servers (like Google) don't always set the
                // Content-Length header field, so we have to listen until
                // they decide to disconnect (or the connection times out).
                if (debugLevel > 1) {
                    response = getHTTPData(serverIn, true);
                    responseLength = Array.getLength(response);
                } else {
                    responseLength = streamHTTPData(serverIn, clientOut, true);
                }

                serverIn.close();
                serverOut.close();
            }

            // send the response back to the client, if we haven't already
            if (debugLevel > 1)
                clientOut.write(response, 0, responseLength);

            // if the user wants debug info, send them debug info; however,
            // keep in mind that because we're using threads, the output won't
            // necessarily be synchronous
            if (debugLevel > 0) {
                long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                debugOut.println("Request from " + pSocket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress() + " on Port "
                        + pSocket.getLocalPort() + " to host " + hostName + ":" + hostPort + "\n  (" + requestLength
                        + " bytes sent, " + responseLength + " bytes returned, " + Long.toString(endTime - startTime)
                        + " ms elapsed)");
                debugOut.flush();
            }
            if (debugLevel > 1) {
                debugOut.println("REQUEST:\n" + (new String(request)));
                debugOut.println("RESPONSE:\n" + (new String(response)));
                debugOut.flush();
            }

            // close all the client streams so we can listen again
            clientOut.close();
            clientIn.close();
            pSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (debugLevel > 0)
                debugOut.println("Error in ProxyThread: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private byte[] getHTTPData(InputStream in, boolean waitForDisconnect) {
        // get the HTTP data from an InputStream, and return it as
        // a byte array
        // the waitForDisconnect parameter tells us what to do in case
        // the HTTP header doesn't specify the Content-Length of the
        // transmission
        StringBuffer foo = new StringBuffer("");
        return getHTTPData(in, foo, waitForDisconnect);
    }

    private byte[] getHTTPData(InputStream in, StringBuffer host, boolean waitForDisconnect) {
        // get the HTTP data from an InputStream, and return it as
        // a byte array, and also return the Host entry in the header,
        // if it's specified -- note that we have to use a StringBuffer
        // for the 'host' variable, because a String won't return any
        // information when it's used as a parameter like that
        ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        streamHTTPData(in, bs, host, waitForDisconnect);
        return bs.toByteArray();
    }

    private int streamHTTPData(InputStream in, OutputStream out, boolean waitForDisconnect) {
        StringBuffer foo = new StringBuffer("");
        return streamHTTPData(in, out, foo, waitForDisconnect);
    }

    private int streamHTTPData(InputStream in, OutputStream out, StringBuffer host, boolean waitForDisconnect) {
        // get the HTTP data from an InputStream, and send it to
        // the designated OutputStream
        StringBuffer header = new StringBuffer("");
        String data = "";
        int responseCode = 200;
        int contentLength = 0;
        int pos = -1;
        int byteCount = 0;

        try {
            // get the first line of the header, so we know the response code
            data = readLine(in);
            if (data != null) {
                header.append(data + "\r\n");
                pos = data.indexOf(" ");
                if ((data.toLowerCase().startsWith("http")) && (pos >= 0) && (data.indexOf(" ", pos + 1) >= 0)) {
                    String rcString = data.substring(pos + 1, data.indexOf(" ", pos + 1));
                    try {
                        responseCode = Integer.parseInt(rcString);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        if (debugLevel > 0)
                            debugOut.println("Error parsing response code " + rcString);
                    }
                }
            }

            // get the rest of the header info
            while ((data = readLine(in)) != null) {
                // the header ends at the first blank line
                if (data.length() == 0)
                    break;
                header.append(data + "\r\n");

                // check for the Host header
                pos = data.toLowerCase().indexOf("host:");
                if (pos >= 0) {
                    host.setLength(0);
                    host.append(data.substring(pos + 5).trim());
                }

                // check for the Content-Length header
                pos = data.toLowerCase().indexOf("content-length:");
                if (pos >= 0)
                    contentLength = Integer.parseInt(data.substring(pos + 15).trim());
            }

            // add a blank line to terminate the header info
            header.append("\r\n");

            // convert the header to a byte array, and write it to our stream
            out.write(header.toString().getBytes(), 0, header.length());

            // if the header indicated that this was not a 200 response,
            // just return what we've got if there is no Content-Length,
            // because we may not be getting anything else
            if ((responseCode != 200) && (contentLength == 0)) {
                out.flush();
                return header.length();
            }

            // get the body, if any; we try to use the Content-Length header to
            // determine how much data we're supposed to be getting, because
            // sometimes the client/server won't disconnect after sending us
            // information...
            if (contentLength > 0)
                waitForDisconnect = false;

            if ((contentLength > 0) || (waitForDisconnect)) {
                try {
                    byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
                    int bytesIn = 0;
                    while (((byteCount < contentLength) || (waitForDisconnect)) && ((bytesIn = in.read(buf)) >= 0)) {
                        out.write(buf, 0, bytesIn);
                        byteCount += bytesIn;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    String errMsg = "Error getting HTTP body: " + e;
                    if (debugLevel > 0)
                        debugOut.println(errMsg);
                    // bs.write(errMsg.getBytes(), 0, errMsg.length());
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (debugLevel > 0)
                debugOut.println("Error getting HTTP data: " + e);
        }

        // flush the OutputStream and return
        try {
            out.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return (header.length() + byteCount);
    }

    private String readLine(InputStream in) {
        // reads a line of text from an InputStream
        StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer("");
        int c;

        try {
            // if we have nothing to read, just return null
            in.mark(1);
            if (in.read() == -1)
                return null;
            else
                in.reset();

            while ((c = in.read()) >= 0) {
                // check for an end-of-line character
                if ((c == 0) || (c == 10) || (c == 13))
                    break;
                else
                    data.append((char) c);
            }

            // deal with the case where the end-of-line terminator is \r\n
            if (c == 13) {
                in.mark(1);
                if (in.read() != 10)
                    in.reset();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (debugLevel > 0)
                debugOut.println("Error getting header: " + e);
        }

        // and return what we have
        return data.toString();
    }

}
```

How i start my server:

```
public void run() {
new jProxy(1099).start();
}
```

How i set my TunnelSocket:

```
TunnelSocket socket = new TunnelSocket("0.0.0.0", 1099, "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 80);
```

Can anyone spot the problem? Am i suppose to do anything at the Server side?
I have tried using TunnelSocket.java over another proxy(Hidemyass), and it worked!

So the problem must be my jProxy.

Can anyone spot the problem? My webserver creates registry on 1099.

**EDIT:** I have now binded my proxy to localhost(127.0.0.1).

```
TunnelSocket socket = new TunnelSocket("127.0.0.1", 1099, "xx.xxx.xxx.xxx", 80);
```

I just read my access.log on my webserver and it says: `CONNECT xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:80 HTTP/1.0" 405 557 "-" "Java/1.7.0" which means it receives my CONNECT but dosen't give me any response.

Should i redirect traffic to 1099 on the server side?

HTTP 405 means "Method not allowed" and i can't figure out why i get it.

Answer (score 0):

Your web server shouldn't have received the CONNECT command. That should only have gone as far as your proxy.

Comment: I've overlooked the log and the timestamp is correct. So the server did get Connect. Anyway, what could be triggering this message in My proxy?

Comment: Maybe i need to enable CONNECT on my webserver? Shouldn't that already be default?